# iOS7 UIWebView doesn't load

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a navigation controller called ClassifiedViewController and it has a webview in the view. Once the webview has loaded, and the user clicks on a link in the webview, I want be able to create a new instance of the class, and push it onto the current navaigation controller, after having loaded the new NSURLRequest.

My code is this:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked)
{
    ClassifiedViewController* newWeb = [[[ClassifiedViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"ClassifiedViewController" bundle: nil] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController: newWeb animated: YES];

    [newWeb.web loadRequest: request];

    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

However, this does not work in iOS 7 but it does eventually work in iOS 6. Any ideas why?

Comment: did you set yourself as the webView's delegate?

Comment: I've added this in `newWeb.web.delegate = self;` but that hasn't made a difference?

Comment: what types of variables are newWeb and web? Can you post some more code?

Comment: newWeb is the name of the new ClassifiedViewController, and web is a property of type UIWebView in the ClassifiedViewController

Comment: is the ClassifiedViewController a UIViewController or a UINavigationController?

Comment: you should call `[self.navigationController pushViewController: newWeb animated: YES];` in `webViewDidFinishLoad:` instead of `shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` since you want to show the `ClassifiedViewController` after the page has loaded.